# Do Transformers have romantic relationships?

Tags: transformers

I was thinking about the lack of feminine or woman Transformers, such as Arcee, and got to wondering if Transformers have romantic affections.

I know they have strong bonds of friendship and loyalty, but the lack of need to reproduce makes me wonder if romance is something they're built to have.

If they do, what are some example relationships?

To clarify, I really just mean romantic, not sexual.

Comment: Well, we know that they've got testicles. That implies sexual reproduction.

Comment: @Valorum - We do? o_O

Comment: @Valorum Or simply tasteless hitch decorations

Comment: I don't know about romantic relationships.  Judging by the fan-art, it seems to be mostly about the sex.

Comment: @Adamant They've added various balls to several in the Michael Bay films

Comment: Why am now I thinking about the humping robot from Robot Chicken?

Comment: @PeterM  I was hoping someone would have posted a gif of that but that'll do thank you!

Comment: They have truck nutz? http://bloglesstroll.blogspot.com/2008/04/now-theyre-busting-truck-nutz.html?m=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While most continuities that include gendered Transformers only mildly hint at romantic relationships, the Beast Wars/Machines franchise

> (and G1 cartoon by extension),

includes a very definitive romantic relationship between [Silverbolt](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Silverbolt_(BW)) and [Blackarachnia](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Blackarachnia_(BW)).

At first, the emotional attachment is one-sided, with Silverbolt professing his love for Blackarachnia, but over time, the relationship is solidified, and they both profess their love for each other.

While no sexual reproduction topics are ever touched, there are scenes in the show where they kissed.

Specific to G1, the cartoon heavily implies that there is a romantic relationship between Orion Pax/Optimus Prime and Ariel/Elita One.

Looking at crossing species...

In [*The Girl Who Loved Powerglide*](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/The_Girl_Who_Loved_Powerglide), Powerglide appears to form a romantic attachment with Astoria.

[image]

In [*Seachange*](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Sea_Change), Seaspray falls in love with the humanoid Alana.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Adding to phantom42's excellent answer, the current Transformers comic books (published by IDW) have indeed confirmed that not only do the Transformers have romantic feelings for each other, some of them have relationships that are analogous to marriages. In the IDW-verse two Cybertronians who love each other can undergo a ritual and become *Conjunx Endura*. Such Cybertronians will almost always be seen at each other's sides, others would describe them as each other's "significant other", and have special legal priviliges towards each other. In the ongoing series "More Than Meets the Eye", the most prominent couple are Chromedome and Rewind.

[image: Chromedome and Rewind]

At one point in the series one of them gets seriously injured in battle and becomes comatose. So medical officer First Aid asks the other for permission to conduct an experimental medical procedure since the usual methods had failed, which is similar to how we humans relay medical decisions to our spouses when we are unable to make them ourselves.

Note that since in the IDW-verse Cybertronians reproduce asexually, gender has no impact on a relationship, and what in human terms would be called same sex marriages are just as common as opposite sex marriages.

[image: Lightbright and Sparkstalker]

Here's Sparkstalker asking Lightbright to become his Conjunx Endura in Transformers Holiday Special (2015).

Comment: Very nice update for me, showing current IDW stuff. I was hoping for some comic-related answer, as well.

Comment: LOL. That's still not spelled right.

Comment: @DCShannon - Hopefully this last edit does it. I *hate* writing Cybertronians for that very reason. I *always* get it wrong :(

Comment: I can't give 2 green checks, or this would get it, too. In spirit, the one is for the both of you. The answers work excellent together, and gave me exactly what I wanted.